# understanding step in a proof: A Comment on Unions of Sigma-Fields Allen Broughton and Barthel W. Huff

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Proving that the union of a countable sequence of strictly increasing sigma algebras is a practice exercise in a book I am studying, Measures, Integrals and Martingales by Rene Schilling. I was unable to solve this question and looked at the solution. I understand steps 1 to 4.

However, I cannot understand the final step (step 5). The author (who gets the proof from the paper) says that without loss of generality (this without loss of generality isn't justified, so perhaps I am missing somethign obvious?) we can identify the sequence of sigma-algebras with one on the integers. For instance, some of the statements do not have obvious counterparts (at least to me) for a generic sigma algebra. For instance, 'Let $B_n$ be the smallest set in $A_n$ containing ${n}$', I don't see how this would be well defined over an arbitrary sigma-algebra. (While you can consider intersection of all sets containing a set, this may not be in a sigma algebra, as only under countable unions and intersections can we be guaranteed to stay in the sigma algebra)
[image]

[image]